# Custom text on toggle buttons not setting when fragment is created

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

I'm working on a fragment that contains three toggle buttons at the moment. In the fragments layout I have:

```
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/corkRdToggle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collegeStToggle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/allRoomsToggle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

In my fragments onViewCreated() method I'm finding the toggle buttons by id, setting both the 'on' and 'off' text, and setting one button to be active:

```
    corkRdToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.corkRdToggle);
    collegeStToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.collegeStToggle);
    allRoomsToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.allRoomsToggle);

    corkRdToggle.setTextOn("Cork Rd.");
    collegeStToggle.setTextOn("College St.");
    allRoomsToggle.setTextOn("All Rooms");

    collegeStToggle.setTextOff("College St.");
    allRoomsToggle.setTextOff("All Rooms");
    corkRdToggle.setTextOff("Cork Rd.");

    allRoomsToggle.setChecked(true);
```

And attaching listeners to them:

```
    corkRdToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
    collegeStToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
    allRoomsToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And in my onClick():

```
        case R.id.corkRdToggle:
            if(allRoomsToggle.isChecked() || collegeStToggle.isChecked()){
                allRoomsToggle.setChecked(false);
                collegeStToggle.setChecked(false);
            }
            corkRdToggle.setChecked(true);

        break;

        case R.id.collegeStToggle:
            if(allRoomsToggle.isChecked() || corkRdToggle.isChecked()){
                allRoomsToggle.setChecked(false);
                corkRdToggle.setChecked(false);
            }
            collegeStToggle.setChecked(true);

        break;

        case R.id.allRoomsToggle:
            if(corkRdToggle.isChecked() || collegeStToggle.isChecked()){
                corkRdToggle.setChecked(false);
                collegeStToggle.setChecked(false);
            }
            allRoomsToggle.setChecked(true);

        break;
```

I have the three toggle buttons, they're linked to the buttons in the layout, the text has been set for both on and off states, and the 'All Rooms' button has been set to be active by default when the screen is created. Whichever button is pressed will become active, while deactivating both others. Everything is working fine.....except for the initial state. When the screen is created the 'All Rooms' button is indeed activated, and shows the text, but the other two toggle buttons only show 'OFF':

[When screen is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kofcm.png)

Pressing either of them will deactivate the 'All Rooms' button and the proper text will display in all buttons:

[Proper text showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEE5u.png)

This remains the case for as long as the screen is being used (due to my rep I can only post 2 links, take my word that it's working).

However the problem is back when I recreate the screen. Done a good bit of looking into this but there doesn't seem to be any info relating to this specifically, and my novice skills are exhausted. If anything jumps out at you I'd really appreciate the pointer, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to setChecked(false) initially on the ones not showing the correct initial text?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked, you beauty! Much appreciated Rui, thank you! Do you want to put it in an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Just did it, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `setOnClickListener()`, try `setOnCheckChangeListener()`

```
corkRdToggle.setOnCheckChangeListener(this);
collegeStToggle.setOnCheckChangeListener(this);
allRoomsToggle.setOnCheckChangeListener(this);
```

I tend to only use `onClickListener` for toggles when i want to specifically control if the toggle should indeed be toggled on click (eg. i want to show a warning first or something)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joe, I'll look into that in the morning. I tried adding Rui's suggestion and that solved the issue I was having, but if it's better practice to use setOnCheckChangeListener I'll try and rework the code when I've recharged. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @Thor IMO this is the standard solution, the above answer is just circumventing the problem, not solving it. `checking` the toggle should fire your listeners, which will in turn uncheck the other toggles, preventing the need to manually call `setChecked()` as you are already doing that within your listeners

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to come back and rectify this, I was moving fast to meet a college deadline and have only now returned to look at the buttons again. You are correct Joe, this is the right answer, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `setChecked(false)` to the other buttons to set the initial state OFF text.